# How to access firebase collection

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I'm  reading  collections  from firebase, string  name, and  image  .  an image URL  from google
Storge on FireBase

```
     _categoryReference.get().then((value) {
          for (int i = 0; i < value.docs.length; i++) {
            _categoryModel.add(CategoryModel.fromJson(value.docs[i].data()));
            print(value.docs[1].data());
```

on  Console, I can print the values from the loop and browse Image Url,
but when comes to display it on wiget ex. Image.network value is  null,
the name is successfully  rendered

Answer (score 1):

Try below code

```
QuerySnapshot query = await _categoryReference.get();

List<String> imageUrls = [];

query.docs.forEach((document) { 
  imageUrls.add(document.data()['imageUrl']); // change ['imageUrl'] to your key which is in document
});

setState((){});
```

Answer (score 0):

I always did it this way:

```
final List<CategoryModel> categories = await _categoryReference.get((snapshot) => snapshot.docs.map((doc) => CategoryModel.fromJson(doc.data()).toList();
```